# How to make a simple 3d object viewer component for already build native iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, unity-game-engine, cocos3d

Several years ago I was curious about creating some objects (spoon, ball, tv, ...) in 3d modeling program, export the textures, and then have a screen in iOS app, that can open one object at a time with a possibility to rotate and zoom it. This seemed quite basic and most used case but I didn't find any simple and ready to use solutions/libraries/plugins, just raw OpenGL ES (GlKit), so I refused to use it, as it would require too much knowledge and time as I haven't done any 3d stuff before and my primary work is not related with 3d.

There are also Unity and Cocos3d engines, and it looks like they allow to extend the code by using iOS plugins (xibs/storyboards, navigation with view controllers and etc), but this means you have to make your app project as Unity/Cocos3d first, and only then add your usual UIKit stuff as a plugin. Now that is not acceptable because the project should be written using UIKit first, and I expect to add 3d viewing stuff as a separate component that encapsulates all the necessary stuff inside it as a black box, because I don't want to mess my project up, as this 3d stuff is an optional feature.

Now, after several years I'v searched for the thing again looking for simple 3d viewing plugins/solutions for UIKit, but the situation is pretty much the same imho. I saw iOS8 there will add  Scene Kit, but I'm not sure will it be something close to what I expect. So, still I'm not sure is there any solution that would require minimum time efforts, or is OpenGL ES the best solution for this need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `CC3DemoMultiScene` demo app in the [latest version](https://github.com/cocos3d/cocos3d/archive/2.0.0.zip) of **Cocos3D**. It demonstrates how to include a *Cocos3D* scene in a standard UIKit storyboard, and to have the GL view only a component of a larger UIView.

Comment: Thanks. Such an honor to receive an answer from the creator of cocos3d.